# .bash_profile inoperable, updating path doesn't resolve the issue

Tags: java, macos, bash

I'm not sure where I went wrong, but I used `nano` to edit my `bash_profile` to install `JavaSDK` on my Mac a few days ago. I have been doing everything in Eclipse, so I haven't had occasion to visit the command line for a few days...until today.

Nothing works. No `ls`, no `nano`, no `vim`...nothing. I tried to type:

`-bash: nano: command not found`

`-bash: ls: command not found`

`defaults write com.apple.finder.AppleShowAllFiles YES` to unhide system files so I can figure out where my `.bash_profile` is and I get this:

`-bash: defaults: command not found`

I'm able to find command line solutions that look promising, but I can't get any commands to be recognized. Any helpful hints would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I've attempted to implement solutions I've found on StackOverflow and elsewhere, yet I'm still finding commands that were previously working are no longer doing so. When I make changes, I log out and back in. Rebooting doesn't seem to do the trick, either.

`echo $PATH` returns the following:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin

Here's my `.bash_profile`:

```
#Setting PATH for Python 2.7
export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv

#Java setup
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin

if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
# RUBY FIX?

# PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin"
export PATH
```

Are there any other places I should be looking? What turned out to be a minor issue a few days ago is turning into a major one, as I can't get any work done.

Comment: The first line `export PATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin` should have `:$PATH` at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `/usr/bin/nano` (not just `nano` because your `PATH` variable is messed up) to edit your `.bash_profile` again.

Remove the line:

```
export PATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
```

As well as the line:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin"
```

First, save this, log out, log in, and make sure that you have all your commands back as you know them.

Then check if you have `python` and `java` available. You should not need to change the `PATH` at all when you have installed Java, and I believe not when you have installed python either. The installation of the Oracle JDK automatically adds `java` to your existing path. At most, you should set the `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: Thank you! You have no idea how much I appreciate this! I have my machine back!